# Placing a WHERE statement separately for a UNION function to work

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by, union, window-functions

I am working on a hackerrank exercise where I have to find the city with the shortest name and with the longest name and if there are many with the same amount of characters in the name then take the first one in alphabetical order

This is the table that was provided

[image: Table]

and after many tries, I managed to create this code that works

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY) AS LENGTH_CITY FROM STATION ORDER BY LENGTH_CITY ASC, CITY) WHERE ROWNUM = 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY) AS LENGTH_CITY FROM STATION ORDER BY LENGTH_CITY DESC, CITY) WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

So my question is, originally I had made this other piece of code that does not work, and I was wondering why do I have to place the "WHERE ROWNUM = 1" separately in a SELECT* for the UNION to work?

```
SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY) AS LENGTH_CITY FROM STATION WHERE ROWNUM = 1 ORDER BY LENGTH_CITY ASC, CITY
UNION
SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY) AS LENGTH_CITY FROM STATION WHERE ROWNUM = 1 ORDER BY LENGTH_CITY DESC, CITY;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was wondering why do I have to place the "WHERE ROWNUM = 1" separately in a SELECT* for the UNION to work?

It has nothing to do with `UNION`, but with `ORDER BY`.

The 2nd query you posted certainly doesn't do what you intended because `WHERE` clause executes before `ORDER BY`, so this:

```
select city
from station
where rownum = 1
order by city
```

says: give me the first *random* row from the table and then sort that row by `city`.

Therefore: first sort rows, then take the first one:

```
select *
from (select city
      from station
      order by city
     )
where rownum = 1
```

Apply that to your situation, *lengths* and stuff.

Comment: Ok, I understand now why the logic does not work on the first table.

But let´s say I wanted to get the first random row in both cases and then put a UNION so I get both results, why is the UNION not working on the second case?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `row_number()` instead of `rownum`. Using it, you don't need `union`, you can just do:

```
select *
from (
    select s.*, 
        row_number() over(order by length(city), city) rn_asc,
        row_number() over(order by length(city) desc, city) rn_desc
    from station s
) s
where 1 in (rn_asc, rn_desc)
```

If you were to do this with `union` (which is less efficient than the above solution), then a row-limiting clause is more appropriate (available starting Oracle 12c):

```
(
    select * 
    from station 
    order by length(city), city 
    fetch first 1 row only
) union all (
    select * 
    from station 
    order by length(city) desc, city 
    fetch first row only
)
```

Comment: ok, but let's say that in my second query both queries separately are correct, then why can't I put a UNION in between them to join them? why does my query work when I have the WHERE clause outside but not on my second query?

I understand now that on my second query the ORDER BY should be first and the WHERE should be after that, but let's assume it is correct, why can't I just put a UNION in between them?